# Why did JSLint mark this line as an error

Tags: jslint

```
/*global THREE Coordinates $ document window*/
```

JSLint says it was expecting */ but got Coordinates instead
 but the line passed when passed when I ran it in Eclipse javascript project.

Answer (score 1):

Js lint thought you were using the `/*global*/` directive. This is used to indicate a variable is global and somewhere else.

See: [JS Lint Global Directive](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#global)

Comment: Which is to say, it expected a *comma* between each global var's name. Not sure why Eclipse's plugin doesn't complain, but jslint.com (the canonical source) would.

Comment: @ruffin, this is not part of Javascript so that's why (I suppose) Eclipse doesn't complain, it is only for JSLint.

Comment: ah, thought he had a JSLint plugin in Eclipse that didn't complain.  Right, valid JavaScript, but, *for the OP*, the `global` line is explicitly for JSLint, not the JavaScript engine!  *JSLint* needs `/*global THREE, Coordinates, $, document, window*/`